# Combobox does not resize properly to fit larger font size

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

When I create a combobox using PyQt5 on MacOS Big Sur, whether using the Designer or using code, the standard font size (13) allows for some padding around the text; this is what I want. A simple code would be:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication([])
    comboBox = qtw.QComboBox()
    comboBox.addItem('My first item')
    comboBox.addItem('My second item')
    comboBox.show()
```

[image]

However when I increase the font size to 25, for example by adding:

```
font = comboBox.font()
font.setPointSize(25)
comboBox.setFont(font)
```

I get the following:

[image]

which is clearly too cramped. Does anyone know how to change this? I get the same result setting the font size in Designer's property editor and setting it in a stylesheet.

Edit: Just tried on Ubuntu and here it works as expected...:

[image]

Comment: Are you using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: No, I'm not using a layout manager; I've updated the example to a minimum reproducible one.

Comment: @Marco Some images that you provide clearly do not correspond to the MRE that you provide since they are a preview of QtDesigner.

Comment: This is true; I've now posted the correct images. Mind you, they're the same...

Comment: If you're changing the font size _after_ the item is shown, and not using a layout, then call `adjustSize()` too.

Comment: @Marco using layout managers is important as one of their purposes is that they ensure that *all* widgets are resized in order to properly show their contents. Avoiding layouts is usually discouraged (especially because it's often based on lack of experience/knowledge), but it *still* is possible to ignore them as long as you *really* know what you're doing. From your example it seems there's no real need for that, so I strongly urge you to get more experienced in layouts before attempting to use that no-layout approach. Long story short, you're getting that because you're not using layouts.

Comment: @Alec Nope, this has no effect...and since Ubuntu resizes the box correctly I'm beginning to think this may be a bug...

Comment: @Musicmante I'm not using a layout here because for this MRE it isn't required; it works fine on Ubuntu but not on Big Sur, so chances are this could be due to a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been accepted as a bug; see [QTBUG-98042](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98042).

Comment: Nice, thank you! Instead of adding it as additional text to the post, make the `QTBUG-98042` text that you added to the answer a link, e.g.: `see [QTBUG-98042](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98042).`